# Vim: Correct the improperly-formatted JSON file

Tags: json, regex, vim

#### Background:

I have a large sets of large JSON files that are improperly formatted. I'd like to use vim command to correct the format to make them all valid JSON.

#### Problems about the JSON files:

1. All keys in these JSON files are not surrounded by `"`.
2. There's no `,` at the end of the non-last JSON entry.

#### input (invalid JSON):

```
...
]
id: "92E121F5-C705-4C2E-9839-0F8491BFC440"
price: "2.00"
options: [ ]
}
...
```

#### output (valid JSON):

```
...
]
"id": "92E121F5-C705-4C2E-9839-0F8491BFC440",
"price": 2.00,
"options": [ ]
}
...
```

#### Question:

How do I transform the input to output as shown above?

---

## Update:

I'm using `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3`

Answer (score 4):

1. All keys in these JSON files are not surrounded by ":

   `:%s/^(\w*):/"\1":/`
2. There's no , at the end of the non-last JSON entry:

   `:%s/$/,/`

   `:%s/},$/}/`

   `:%s/,\n}$/\n}/`
3. Numbers are surrounded by ":

   `:%s/"([0-9]+.[0-9]+)"/\1/`

Comment: For `:%s/^(\w*):/"\1":/`, I get the following error: `Pattern not found: ^(\w)*`. I tried with `:%s/^\w*:/"\1":/` and it is able to search the string that way. But seems like `\1` doesn't work.

Comment: For #1, I did `:%s/^\w*/"\0"/g` then `:%s:""::g`. It worked.